# Python 2 - TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Tags: python, save, load, pickle

How can I fix this error? When I try to load my save in with pickle it gives me this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\game.py", line 315, in <module>
    menu()
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\game.py", line 261, in menu
    if (0) > int(hunger) or (0) > int(thirst):
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

This is how I load/save

```
with open('objs.pickle', "rb") as f:  
    money = pickle.load(f)
    hunger = pickle.load(f)
    thirst = pickle.load(f)
    energy = pickle.load(f)
    wanted = pickle.load(f)
    gun = pickle.load(f)


with open('objs.pickle', 'ab') as f:  
    pickle.dump([money, hunger, thirst, energy, gun, wanted], f)
```

Comment: always put **FULL** error message in **QUESTION**. There are other usefull information.

Comment: I edited it there

Comment: use `print(hunger, thirst)` to see what you have in this variables.

Comment: [1000.0] [1000.0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0]

Comment: `data = pickle.load(f)`, `hunger = data[1]`, `thirst = data[2]`

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: its given me that error now..

Comment: use `'wb'` to write - now you have many rows/lists in file - first has only one element, second has many,

Comment: so instead of ab wb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `'wb'` instead of `'ab'` to have only last values

And later you can use

```
with open('objs.pickle', "rb") as f:  
    money = pickle.load(f)
    hunger = pickle.load(f)
    thirst = pickle.load(f)
    energy = pickle.load(f)
    gun = pickle.load(f)
    wanted = pickle.load(f)


with open('objs.pickle', 'wb') as f:  
    pickle.dump(money, f)
    pickle.dump(hunger, f)
    pickle.dump(thirst, f)
    pickle.dump(energy, f)
    pickle.dump(gun, f)
    pickle.dump(wanted, f)
```

or

```
with open('objs.pickle', "rb") as f:  
    money, hunger, thirst, energy, gun, wanted = pickle.load(f)

with open('objs.pickle', 'wb') as f:  
    pickle.dump([money, hunger, thirst, energy, gun, wanted], f)
```